# GDAL API in C/C++

Tags: c++, gdal

I'm trying to compile the following program (using GDAL API in C++):

main.cpp:

```
#include "gdal_priv.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset* data = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpen( "heightmap.tiff", GA_ReadOnly );


}
```

the way I build it on a Mac :

```
clang main.cpp  -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/unix/include
```

and got this:

```
clang main.cpp  -I/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/unix/include/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GDALOpenShared", referenced from:
      _main in test_gdal-QIB6MK.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
What's wrong with this very basic case?
```

Comment: You need to link to the library. I don't know how it's called, but if it would be `gdal`, the cmdline would need `-lgdal`

Comment: Ok adding -lgdal actually worked for Linux, but not for the Mac. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your project on a Mac using bash file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Path to you installed GDAL
GDAL_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.2.0

INCLUDE_PATH=${GDAL_PATH}/include
LIBS_PATH=${GDAL_PATH}/lib
GDAL_LIB=-lgdal

g++ -I${INCLUDE_PATH} -L${LIBS_PATH} ${GDAL_LIB} main.cpp -o main
```